# Create a subdomain for a internal server

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

I've a domain like domain.com and I've got a new requirements they give me a local server which is a web application and they asked me to create a sub domain that works internally for this server.

the local server is like : http://192.168.2.222/app/

The required sub domains is : http://app.domain.com

I've tried to add A and CNAME records on the dns for the sub domain but it didn't work. any suggestions to how accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **`app.domain.com`** is a **domain name** then you should create new zone depending which server you're using.

If **`app.domain.com`** is a **host name** then you just create A and PTR records in your zone.

Sure, you should have access to write the zone to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

On the DNS server You should point the subdomain to the internal IP.
Furthermore you have to configure your webserver on that host.